# SQL not pulling data from 1 column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have built my own CMS and am using databases *wp_posts* and *wp_postmeta* to populate my site.

When I use SQL it pulls all data apart from the *post_content* field a very strange situation. Can someone look at my query to make sure its okay please?

I am using my own CMS, not using WordPress.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts,wp_postmeta WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND  
          wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 25";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $ID           = $row['ID'];
    $post_title   = $row['post_title'];
    $post_date    = $row['post_date'];
    $post_excerpt = $row['post_excerpt'];    
    $post_content = $row['post_content']; 
    $_wp_attached_file = $row['meta_value'];    
    ?>

    <!-- First Blog Post -->
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3><a href="post.php?p_id=<?php echo $ID; ?>"><font color="white"><?php echo $post_title; ?></font></a></h3>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> <?php  echo humanTiming( strtotime($post_date) );  ?>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <img class="col-md-4" align="left" width="148" src="images/<?php echo $_wp_attached_file; ?>" alt="">
            <p><?php echo $post_content; ?></p>
        </div>
        <p align="right"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="post.php?p_id=<?php echo $ID; ?>">Read More <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"> </span></a></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: In the query `wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' ` seems to refer to a constant string. Did you mean something like `'$_wp_attached_file'`?

Comment: no the _wp_attached_file is in the postmeta data of my wordpress site as i was using a custom post type of stories, it has taken so long to get the tables to work together, and i have finally got them working together but had 1 problem which is the post_content in my code will not display but the _wp_attached_file works and the title and date all except the content , and yet it amazes me how i am down voted for a few mistakes in my title am only seeking help

Comment: Still require help as the only field that will not pull data is post_content

Answer (score 2):

This answer is more advice than answer.  This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND  
      wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 25;
```

This is what your query should look like:

```
SELECT p.id, p.post_title, p.post_date, p.post_excerpt, p.post_content,
       pm.meta_value as wp_attached_file
FROM wp_posts p JOIN
     wp_postmeta pm
     ON p.ID = pm.post_id  
WHERE pm.meta_key = ?
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 25;
```

I think the fix to your problem is the listing of the columns in the header.  This avoids naming collisions.

Other changes:

- Use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Name the columns by what they are in the `SELECT`.
- Use table aliases and qualified column names.
- Pass in parameters as *parameters* rather than munging the query string.

If you want to learn how to code PHP and MySQL, you might as well learn to do it correctly.

Comment: currently i am taking a course, i accidently said i was using INNER JOIN when that was the code i was using, my code was working but just was not pulling out the post_content, i have added your code and am trying to get it to display everything as i am getting undefined variables thanks for the help

Comment: how would i go about echoing the value in a fetch_assoc or array? only worked with assoc so far